# Attendance report with power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to build a Power BI report with respect to attendance. I am new to power BI and i am finding it hard to arrive at the correct logic.

So my data looks something like this

[image]

And I need an output like this

[image]

So basically, The days attended columns should contain the number of days attended based on the date mentioned. For example, No 3 attended on 10th of May first. So his value in days attended column is 1 and he attended again on 13th, so his value becomes 2

Can someone please help. I've been stuck with this for quite a while now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a measure as below-

```
days_attended = 
calculate(
    count(your_table_name[unique_id]),
    filter(
        allexcept(your_table_name,your_table_name[unique_id]),
        your_table_name[Date] <= min(your_table_name[Date])
    )
)
```

Here is the code for new column-

```
days_attended_column = 

var curr_row_id  = your_table_name[unique_id]
var curr_row_date  = your_table_name[Date]

Return
calculate(
    count(your_table_name[unique_id]),
    filter(
        all(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[unique_id] = curr_row_id
            && your_table_name[Date] <=  curr_row_date
    )
)
```

here is the sample output-

[image]

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani
 
I used the following code. But i am not getting the desired result for some reason.

Days_attended = 
calculate(
    COUNT('Combined Attendance data'[GGID]),
    filter(
        allexcept('Combined Attendance data','Combined Attendance data'[GGID]),
        'Combined Attendance data'[Date] <= min('Combined Attendance data'[Date])
    )
)

I can see a lot of blanks in between and all the inputs are just 1. So its either 1s or blanks. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you creating a Measure? Or a column? If it is a measure, it should work. Is it possible you share a screenshot of your output?

Comment: Another thing, do you have proper date type value in date column? It's a prerequisite.

Comment: I am creating a column actually Not the measure. If i create a measure i dont think i cant add that as a column in my table. Can i?

Forgive my ignorance. i am very new to power BI

Comment: I should have been more clear, The excel snapshot i showed is actually the file i uploaded not the table or the matrix visual

Comment: @SUMANNUTAKKI I have added the code for creating a new column. Please accept the answer and put an up vote if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Someone will quickly jump in with DAX method, but if you wanted to do this in Powerquery/M, right click Unique ID, group by... provide a column name, use operation All Rows, and hit ok. In the formula bar then change the part starting with word **each** to instead be

```
 each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "DaysAttended", 1, 1, Int64.Type), type table}})
```

Use arrows atop the new column to expand the extra columns. Change column types and re-sort as desired

Full sample code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Unique ID"}, {{"data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "DaysAttended", 1, 1, Int64.Type), type table}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Date", "Index"}, {"Date", "Index"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

[image]