# Dynamic value Change in Calculated Column With Slicer Filter On Report Page

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am facing an issue and I am not even sure if it is possible to achieve the desired outcome.

So basically, I have a table like this.

[image]

So every time an employee enters the office, his unique ID is recorded in the system.

and I Have a master file where I have the list of all the employees and their details. it looks something like this.
[image]

Now i am trying to create an interactive pie chart where I get the count of employees in the values column and the days attended in the legend. something like this.

[image]

The pie chart should be interactive in such a way that when I use date in the slicer and I filter the dates from May 10th - May 11th, I should get the split of people who came for 0 days, 1 day and so on.

Please let me know if this can be done and how can i arrive at the result. I have been stuck at this for a while now.

Comment: Sorry, to ask: What have you tried since [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76271544/attendance-report-with-power-bi) and where you are stuck? It would be easier to answer if you could provide more specifics.

Comment: So i added an additional column in the master data which give me the value of the number of times the unique ID is repeated in the attendance list.

Attended days in May= CALCULATE(COUNT('Attendance '[UniqueID]), ALLEXCEPT('MASTERDATA', 'MASTERDATA'[UniqueID]))

But this gives me momentary data. and this doesn't change with date. So i am stuck here

Comment: I would recommend you to do more reading into this hole topic, e.g. when to use calculated tables/columns vs. measures. Calculated tables and columns in DAX are computed/updated during data refresh, when your data model is created, and will not change with any filter/slicer selection while using your data model. A lot of fundamental concepts can be found e.g. here: www.sqlbi.com (the website of the famous duo Alberto and Marco) Good luck!